# Why does Xcode constantly show Loading... all the time after project files have loaded?

Tags: xcode

I have loaded an app, GoSiteUK, into Xcode 14.2 and Xcode constantly shows that it is still loading the project.

I have tried closing the project and quiting Xcode then deleting the directories;

```
GoSiteUK.xcodeproj/xcuserdata
GoSiteUK.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
```

Then deleted the DerivedData directory, opened Xcode up again and loaded the project, cleaned the build folder and re-built the app. But it still shows `GoSiteUK Loading...`

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the project and cloned the git repo back to my macBookPro and it is working now.